# Votos dados no perfil está diferente: "listagem de votos" x "impacto votos dados"

Tags: bug, status-intencional, votos, perfil

No meu perfil do [sopt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17340/david?tab=summary), tenho no totalizador de impacto 1953 votos, ja na listagem de votos, tenho 1836. Conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que isso é um bug? Ou existe algum outro tipo de calculo feito para determinar o impacto? Se Sim gostaria de saber.

Comment: Não, aquele contador do seu perfil contabiliza todos os votos que você já deu desde a criação do perfil de postagens ainda ativos no site. O contador da listagem da aba votos, no seu caso em especifico, não irá mostrar votos em posts que ja se encontram deletados, por isso da uma quantidade menor. Veja no meu caso, se voce for no meu perfil, terá quase 10 mil votos, mas o que aparece pra mim na aba de votos é algo proximo de 15 mil, pois como tenho  mais de 10.000, eu tenho acesso a posts removidos, portanto, é listado para mim votos em posts removidos.

Comment: Entendi @Articuno, obrigado :)

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que o primeiro contador so contabiliza votos contra e favor em perguntas/respostas, e esse do print conta todos os seus votos, incluindo fechamento de perguntas, e outros tipos de votos que vão sendo liberados a medida que se aumenta a reputação.

Comment: No meu caso so tenho votos `a favor` e `contra`, e fiz a conta e bate a soma.

Comment: Teria melhor visibilidade enquanto resposta, o teu comentário, @Articuno ;)